# Changed cursor theme

Tags: cursor-theme

I recently updated my ubuntu to 14.04. Afterwards i started customizing it a bit using unity tweak tool. Tryed some stuff, then decided to go back to default theme. Thing is that, after switching the themes, i reset to default in unity tweak tool and now my cursor is black. Tryed a bunch of stuff to get it back to white, but to no succes. If i go in dconf-editor, the DMZ-White theme for the cursor is selected. Is it  possible i somehow deleted the white cursor file or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

Pick the theme you want using a number, then *reboot* (not logout)